# How to run multiple chrome profiles in selenium c#?

Tags: c#

How can I run multiple chrome profiles at the same time?

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

var service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();

service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

options.AddArgument("--user-data-dir=profiles);

var driver = new ChromeDriver(service, options);

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://ip-api.com");
```

I want to run all the records I have created in a directory simultaneously and perform the `driver.Navigate () action. GoToUrl ("http://ip-api.com/json/");` without having to repeat it many times.